# Use nativeQuery=true with @Query in Spring-Boot does not work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring Boot project I have this pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
....
```

I want to use a custom native query in one of the repositories

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true, "select * from question q where q.id < 5")
public Collection<QuestionEntity> queryAnnotated();
```

But as I want to give the parameter nativeQuery = true, I get a syntax error

```
Syntax error on token ""select * from question q where q.id < 5"", invalid MemberValuePair
```

Comment: try this: `select q.* from question q where q.id < 5`

Comment: it does not make any differences

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use your @Query like this:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="select * from question q where q.id < 5")
public Collection<QuestionEntity> queryAnnotated();
```

The `value` tag was missing in your example. The `question` table and the column `q.id` should exactly match with your table and column names of your Database.

In my test application it works:

```
@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, long>{

    @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT * FROM Question q where q.id < 5")
    public Collection<Question> findQuestion();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Change the query and method as per your business requirement. Hope it works.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = ?0", nativeQuery = true)
  User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```

Comment: I checked it. It makes no difference.